# Redirect all traffic from nonwww to www and https to http

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl, https, no-www

I found every combination on the net except of this one. How do I redirect all traffic in a generic way to the "http://www."?

So that happens:

```
domain.com --> http://www.domain.com
www.domain.com --> http://www.domain.com
https://domain.com/page --> http://www.domain.com/page
```

etc.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

This way

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

So all you need to use is:

```
RewriteEngine On

#Force WWW on everything
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#Check to see if HTTPS, if so, make HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This will force WWW and HTTP on everything.

Comment: Thanks but `https://www.example.com` doesn't redirect to `http://www.example.com`. `https://example.com` redirects correctly to `http://www.example.com`